# how to align these input fields with this image, so that i will not have gap in between

Tags: css, layout, bootstrap-4

I want MAP PO and select status below the above input fields without the gap in between, the image is interrupting the flow.

The image:

[image]

Comment: Edit the question and include the code please.

Comment: Yup, use jsfiddle.net or codepen.io to display code so that people can help you better.

Comment: @wing No, the best way is to use the stackoverflow snippet, so we don't have to open a link to see it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
   <form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label for="inputState">Select Hardware</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label for="inputCity">Serial Tag</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label for="inputZip">Assset No.</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label for="inputCity">Map No</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label for="inputState">Slect Status</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
   </div>
   <div class="col-auto">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)

Comment: i'm using bootstrap... if you can help me in that... i'm posting my html here

Comment: sure, why not @SrishtiBhargava

Comment: what you want @SrishtiBhargava

Comment: beacuse of image , the 2nd row is not aligned properly, means there is some space in between them,because of image height

Comment: thanx a lot arpan :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code it is particularly hard to give you a direct answer.

However I suggest you apply `position: relative` to both *MAP PO* and *Select Status*, as well as their input fields (possibly by containing them all within a `<div>` and applying the position to that container).

Then you will be able to use both `top` and `bottom` as well as `margin-bottom` and `margin-top` properties to adjust the positioning.

More on positioning can be read at: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp.

It is best to use relative units such as `%` and `em` for positioning, as this allows for a responsive layout.